# HREF Tel Not Working with Yahoo Mobile Android

Tags: android, yahoo, tel

`<a href="tel:1.888.222.3333">`

is not working on yahoo android devices. Working fine on Android Gmail, AOL, Outlook. Its rendering like

```
<a rel="nofollow">
```

in yahoo mail chrome debug mode. 
Any one has idea how to fix this issue

Comment: totally stuck with this issue, please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using tel://1-888-222-3333 instead for emails.